# Codeigniter Get Values from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to list some data from two tables. I am trying to do this:
From table users I am trying to list from table "firm_info" firms added for the current user.
The idea:

#### John

- firm 1
- firm 2
- firm 3

#### Michael

- no firms listed

#### Joe

- firm 1
- firm 2

Comment: What? Please explain. Use short simple sentences.

Comment: I am trying to list all users from table "users" and list all firms from table "firm_info" added for that user.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to is a [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) on users and firms table.

In this case your left table would be users. Hope you find the above link helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's all on the documentation. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html 
Search for the function `$this->db->join();` and btw i just answered the same question like 10 minutes again. Use the stackoverflow search function next time.

From codeigniter user_guide

**$this->db->join();**

```
Permits you to write the JOIN portion of your query:

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces:
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

Comment: I tried using join but the problem is, if there is not firm added for the user, the user is not shown in the table

Comment: try `$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id','left');

$query = $this->db->get();` Note the `'left'` added at `$this->db->join()`

Comment: yes, I used the left join statement, but if there are two firms added for the user it adds another row 
like:
 
user1 - firm1
user1 - firm2
I need it:
`user1
-firm1
-firm2
`

Comment: I think there should be another loop for displaying the firms for the user, but i dont know how to make loop inside that loop

Comment: then you must also add `$this->db->group_by('user_id);` before `$this->db->get();`